# How can I have a ttk.progressbar call a function when it is completed (Python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to have a ttk progressbar call a function that adds to a value that is displayed in the Tkinter window. I currently have a function that is called at the same time the progressbar begins:

```
def bar1_addVal():
     global userMoney
     userMoney += progBar1_values.value
     moneyLabel["text"] = ('$' + str(userMoney))
     canvas1.after((progBar1_values.duration*100), bar1_addVal)
     return
```

but I cannot seem to get the exact amount of time it takes for the progressbar to finish each iteration. Is there a way to have the progressbar call a function every time it completes?

Comment: maybe you should use `variable=` in progressbar with IntVar to keep current value, and use this IntVar with `textvariable=` in Label to update text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `threading` to check for the variable in a loop. Then you wont interrupt the main loop.
I made a little example of this:

```
import threading, time
from ttk import Progressbar, Frame
from Tkinter import IntVar, Tk


root = Tk()


class Progress:

    val = IntVar()
    ft = Frame()
    ft.pack(expand=True)
    kill_threads = False  # variable to see if threads should be killed

    def __init__(self):
        self.pb = Progressbar(self.ft, orient="horizontal", mode="determinate", variable=self.val)
        self.pb.pack(expand=True)
        self.pb.start(50)

        threading.Thread(target=self.check_progress).start()


    def check_progress(self):
        while True:
            if self.kill_threads:  # if window is closed
                return             # return out of thread
            val = self.val.get()
            print(val)
            if val > 97:
                self.finish()
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def finish(self):
        self.ft.pack_forget()
        print("Finish!")


progressbar = Progress()


def on_closing():       # function run when closing
    progressbar.kill_threads = True  # set the kill_thread attribute to tru
    time.sleep(0.1)  # wait to make sure that the loop reached the if statement
    root.destroy()   # then destroy the window

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing) # bind a function to close button

root.mainloop()
```

Edit: Updated the answer, to end the thread before closing window.

Comment: This works perfectly while the Tkinter window is open! There is, however, a runtime error that occurs upon closing the window and it says that the main thread is not present in the main loop. Out of curiosity, why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: @A.Plattus Yes, I updated the answer, to handle that